# What are the causes (and fixes) for extremely long quitting times in Firefox?

Tags: macos, firefox, osx-snow-leopard, osx-leopard

When quitting Firefox (currently v. 3.6.13, but seen on previous versions), the quitting process often takes several minutes (I've timed it up to 7 on some occasions), during which time the fans on my Macbook often start to scream like crazy. The time to quit seems to be directly proportional to the number of days I've had Firefox open without quitting it.

I can make a guess about why this takes so long (cache cleanup, cookie cleanup), but 3-7 minutes is unreasonable. The questions then become

- What is the actual cause of this delay?
- Beyond quitting once or twice a day, is there a way to avoid this delay upon quitting (an extension, a setting)?

Comment: This question cannot be answered negatively ("No, nobody else has problems"). Please rephrase to e.g. make this a troubleshooting/problem identification question.

Comment: Also, please add version numbers (are you using beta versions, for example?) and which plugins are you using - those tend to affect behavior.

Comment: I've had similar problems with Firefox 3.x. It doesn't actually freeze, but takes a very long time (several minutes) to quit. I find the FF 4.x Beta to be quicker, but it still takes some time to quit.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you have one or more plugins that are affecting the closing of your browser.  If you go through the addons you have installed (Tools menu select Addons then Plugins) Remove any that you feel are not needed.  Also do a complete scan of your system for malware / spyware.  These can also greatly slow down your system and affect your internet browser as well as other applications.